# How to create objects from readLine until you reach "END"

Tags: java, class, object, exception

```
private static final String END = "";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception,IOException{
        try {
        String line=null;
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String pizzaInfo[]=line.split(" ");
        String pizzaName=pizzaInfo[1];
        String doughInfo[]=line.split(" ");
        Dough dough=new Dough(doughInfo[1],doughInfo[2],Double.parseDouble(doughInfo[3]));
        Pizza pizza=new Pizza(pizzaName,dough);
        String toppingInfo[]=line.split(" ");
        while(!toppingInfo.equals("END")) {
            Topping newt=new Topping(toppingInfo[1],Double.parseDouble(toppingInfo[2]));
            pizza.addTopping(newt);
        }
        System.out.println(pizza.getName()+"  "+ pizza.calcTotalCalories());
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

So my problem is that the output of this is "java.lang.NullPointerException".

*The input must be:*

**Pizza meatless 2**

**Dough wholegrain crispy 100**

**Topping vegies 90**

**Topping cheese 50**

**END**

*And output for example:*

**meatless -370.00**

To sum up i have 3 classes: 
1. Pizza(String name,List,Dough dough) 
2. Dough(String flour,String baking,double weight) 
3.Topping(String type,double weight).
 I have given types and calories and my program should print in this main function the type and the calories(like i show in the output).
Pizza and dough should be writen on only 1 line while toppings could be some(every topping is on different line).

Comment: I can't see you reading the line into the variable - that may be the problem. Which code line gives you NullPointer?

Comment: String line=null;

Comment: hi Amanda - I'm not sure that can be the case as that couldn't cause NullPointer. I think it is more likely the first time you call split, as I think line is null at that point.

Comment: So how can i make it work read the lines, split them and finally do the methods?

Comment: If that is so, I think you need to use br to read a line of input into line before each call to split

Comment: I think that might be the best - does BufferedReader have a readLine method? I can't remember off the top of my head, but if so maybe loop round calling that until you reach end value, adding each line to a List, then at the end go through the List handling each entry as above ie first one create Pizza, second create dough, remainder create toppings

Comment: String pizzaInfo[]=br.split(" ");     -> i made it like this and it gives me error: The method split(String) is undefined for the type Buffered Reader.

Comment: Ah yes, good - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--

Comment: Yep, it's readLine you need - that gives you a String that you can then split